# Signed apk not generate in React-native, How can I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I generate signed APK in react native for android, then a message will be shown a success. but "release" directory not generated?

/ProjectName/android/app/build/outputs/apk

Show only debug folder

Comment: You probably haven't generated a signing key. Please follow this guide https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

Comment: @KamranNazir I have followed all step properly but still I have face this problem